# Vertical RecyclerView inside Vertical RecyclerView scroll Problem?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I must implement comments list with replies. I use same Item for comment and it's reply. But when I have multiple replies for comment and scroll up to it Recycler View lost position while binding that item.

```
public void setItem(Adaptable item) {
        super.setItem(item);
        this.comment = (Comment) item;
        binding.setComment(comment);
        binding.setViewHolder(this);
        binding.tvMessage.setText(getFormattedText());
        initReplies();
    }

private void initReplies() {
        if (comment.repliesCount <= 0) {
            binding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return;
        }
        binding.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        if (adapter == null) {
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragment.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);              
            binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(fragment, Pages.ID_COMMENTS_REPLY, false);
        }
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addItems(new ArrayList<>(comment.replies), getCommentMeta());
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

setItem method I call from onBindViewHolder